# MVVM DataGrid SelectedItem is always null

Tags: wpf, select, mvvm, datagrid, row

I cannot get the `SelectedItem`, row selection works but retrived `SelectedItem` is `null`.

**View Model:**

```
// Binding DataGrid ItemSource   
public ObservableCollection<Message> TableDataGrid_ItemSource { get; set; }

// Binding DataGrid SelectedItem
private Message _tableDataGrid_SelectedItem;
public Message TableDataGrid_SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _tableDataGrid_SelectedItem; }
            set { _tableDataGrid_SelectedItem = value;  
                  MessageRemovetButton_IsEnabled = true;
                  OnPropertyChanged(); }
         }
```

**xaml:**

```
  <DataGrid 
        Name="TableDataGrid" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding TableDataGrid_ItemSource}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding TableDataGrid_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    >
```

**Code:**

```
MessageBox.Show(_messageManagerViewModel.TableDataGrid_SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `set` to see if it gets hit when you change the selection. Also, look at the **Output Window** for binding errors.

Comment: It gets hit when a row is selected, but then I call this command   private void _doRemoveMessage_Command() {           MessageManagerMainWindow.RemoveMessage(TableDataGrid_SelectedItem);} and TableDataGrid_SelectedItem is null.

Comment: When the setter gets hit, what is the content of value? and where is the command code located?

Comment: The content is a Message type object. I fixed the binding. Was calling it 2 times. Thanks!

Comment: (off topic, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)